# Giving click event only to parent div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have created a overlay and inside that overlay there's another div. I want to close the overlay when the user click on the overlay part and not do anything if the user clicks the child div. I have implemented the closing the overlay function.But the issue is it closes the overlay even if the user clicks on the child div. How can I fix this?

```
<div id="overlay" onClick={this.props.hideOverlay}>

                <div className="ques_preview_div">

                </div>
</div>
```

So basically the overlay should not close if the user clicks somewhere in this div.

```
<div className="ques_preview_div">

</div>
```

Comment: pasting more code helps!

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28511207/react-js-onclick-event-handler - or at least, the answers to that questions should help to solve this (checking event.target in the click handler)

Comment: What do you use to "close" the overlay?

Comment: I use this for onClick event in the overlay div >>>

this.setState({
            showComponent: false,

        });

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer did not work therefore I created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNeWVE)

```
function childClick(event){
  event.stopPropagation()
  console.log('child')
}
```

the problem is based on event bubbling of the child. So if the child is clicked although it does not have a onClick function it still bubbles upwards -> the parent onClick is called. To prevent this we have to add a onClick for the child and simply stopPropagation()