# React.js and jquery Uncaught ReferenceError: (function) is not defined at HTMLTableRowElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

js in my web app, i was just creating table with work, but sadly onClick on a  `Uncaught ReferenceError: (function) is not defined     at HTMLTableRowElement.onclick`

here is table code   `$("#usertable").append("<tr onclick=\"displaySmth('" + smth_value + "')\"><td>" + username + "</tr></td>");`

and function to display `smth_value`

```
   displaySmth(somevalue){
    $("#smth_id").text(somevalue)
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to share a bit more code. Where do you add the onclick listener?

Comment: oh sorry, i just failed while writing this question, updated it already, now you can see the onclick listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way you're adding your click listener, the `displaySmth` function has to be a direct child of the `window` object; if you're using React.js then this probably isn't the case.

A more [common way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32703745/9420243) to add click listeners in React is to inject the function itself (rather than the name), like this:

```
$("#usertable").append(
    <tr onclick={displaySmth}><td>{username}</td></tr>
);
```

This is a touch more complicated when you want to use parameters in your listener, but the concept is the same.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no need to user quotation marks? when im using simple   `$("#usertable").append( <tr><td>+username+</td></tr>)` its not even giving me usernames in table

Comment: It depends a bit on where the code is; if it's in a file that get's compiled (which is most common with react) then quotation marks around html-ish objects aren't needed, but if it's in a non-compiled js file then they will be. [This](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-tables-in-react-part-one--cms-29682) is a pretty good tutorial for getting started with tables in React